# TeeChart Delphi XE3 resize charts when form is resized

Tags: delphi, teechart

Delphi XE3

I have 4 charts on a tabsheet, 2 across, 2 down.  When I resize the form I want the charts to resize proportionately keeping their relative position.  I just can't figure out how to do it.  I've tried using Anchor settings without success. When I set the anchors to Left, Top, Right and Bottom they overlap each other when resized.

Comment: You'll need to resize them manually in the `OnResize` event of the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anchors won't help here. You are looking for something more akin to the `Align` property. But none of the built-in options can do this layout.  So, I think you are best writing a bespoke `OnResize` handler.

I suggest that you put the charts in a container, say a panel. Assuming that you want the charts to fill the panel in a two by two grid, then you write the following in your panel's `OnResize` event handler:

```
var
  W, H: Integer;
....
W := Panel.ClientWidth;
H := Panel.ClientHeight;
Chart1.SetBounds(0, 0, W div 2, H div 2);
Chart2.SetBounds(W div 2, 0, W - W div 2, H div 2);
Chart3.SetBounds(0, H div 2, W div 2, H - H div 2);
Chart4.SetBounds(W div 2, H div 2, W - W div 2, H - H div 2);
```

You can tweak the layout as you please, but the basics of using `OnResize` are the same.